# Do dying asymptotes leave holes in iterated asymptote functions?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I've noticed that for certain functions, where $f(x)$ is rational and has an asymptote, that as the function is iterated, the asymptote becomes slower and moves. And when iterated infinitely converges to some value. This will eventually just be a hole, since every other point is well defined, except maybe this point.

For instance, when $f(x)=\frac1{1+x}$, $f(x)=x$ has two solutions $a,b$ where $a<b$. $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=b$, But the asymptote moves to $x=a$ over time, so is the function defined where the asymptote converges to or not?

I don't think it will be a hole but I can't come up with a good argument as to why it would be defined.

Also please add tags as you see fit, thank you.